# T-SQL: Select using sub Select returns nothing

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Using SQL Server 2008 R2 I currently have this query which works as expected.  It returns a simple distinct list, `catalogID` and `catType`.

Note - the `catType` string is not normalized in `ALM_Catalog` hence the inner select

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    catalogID, catType 
FROM 
    ALM_Catalog cat1 
WHERE 
    cat1.CatalogID = (SELECT max(CatalogID) 
                      FROM ALM_Catalog cat2 
                      WHERE cat1.catType = cat2.catType)
ORDER BY 
    catType;
```

I now have an `ALM_CatalogAudience` table. This is a linking table which has two columns `catalogID` and `businessGroupID`. It is designed to only show certain catalog items to certain business groups.

So I changed the above query to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    cat1.catalogID, cat1.catType 
FROM 
    ALM_Catalog cat1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ALM_CatalogAudience ON cat1.catalogID = ALM_CatalogAudience.catalogID
WHERE 
    cat1.CatalogID = (SELECT MAX(CatalogID) 
                      FROM ALM_Catalog cat2 
                      WHERE cat1.catType = cat2.catType)
    AND ALM_CatalogAudience.businessGroupID = (SELECT  md_businessGroup.businessGroupID  
                                               FROM 
                                                  ((directory d  
                                               LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                                                  md_department ON d.departmentID =  md_department.departmentID)
                                               LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                                                  md_businessGroup ON md_department.businessGroupID = md_businessGroup.businessGroupID) 
                                               WHERE directoryID = 18230)
ORDER BY 
    cat1.catType;
```

Which returns nothing and I can not see why.  Note - The second sub select (SELECT  md_businessGroup...) returns 1 and when I run this:

```
select * from ALM_CatalogAudience where businessGroupID=1
```

it returns 132 records. What am I missing? Thank you in advance.

EDIT:  Some sample output is:

```
1362    Accessories & Parts
1368    Audio & Video
1399    Batteries & Power
1412    Cables & Connectors
1418    Carrying Cases
1424    Docks & Port Replicators
1429    Keyboards & Mice
```

EDIT: It appears that the location of this:

```
cat1.CatalogID = (SELECT MAX(CatalogID) MAX
```

was the mistake I made.  The MAX catalogID was not necessarily mapped to businessGroupID 1 unless of course the catalog item was only ever mapped to one business group which happened to be 1.  So Im sure this is what will work for me now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  max(cat1.catalogID) , cat1.catType FROM ALM_Catalog cat1
left outer join ALM_CatalogAudience on cat1.catalogID = ALM_CatalogAudience.catalogID
WHERE 
 ALM_CatalogAudience.businessGroupID = ( 
    SELECT  md_businessGroup.businessGroupID  
    from directory d  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN md_department 
              on d.departmentID =  md_department.departmentID 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN md_businessGroup 
              on md_department.businessGroupID = md_businessGroup.businessGroupID 
    where directoryID=18230)
group BY cat1.catType
order BY cat1.catType;
```

Comment: Some sample input and expected output would be nice.

Comment: Hi Tim I have added output.   There really is not input.  This is returned to a webService call.  The call is getAlltTpes the directoryID=18230 values is in an application level variable.  Hope that helps

Comment: distinct after group by in this case is senseless

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT cat1.catalogID, cat1.catType 
  FROM ALM_Catalog cat1
 left outer join ALM_CatalogAudience 
   on cat1.catalogID = ALM_CatalogAudience.catalogID
WHERE 
   cat1.CatalogID=
        (SELECT max(CatalogID) from ALM_Catalog cat2 WHERE cat1.catType=cat2.catType)
   AND ALM_CatalogAudience.businessGroupID = 
      (
          SELECT  md_businessGroup.businessGroupID  
            from directory d  
         LEFT OUTER JOIN md_department 
                      on d.departmentID =  md_department.departmentID 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN md_businessGroup 
                      on md_department.businessGroupID = md_businessGroup.businessGroupID 
         where directoryID=18230
      )
  ORDER BY cat1.catType;
```

I m suprised that you don't get a syntax error. i just fixed it and changed nothing, if it still won't work, then we need some sample data.

Ok, since still no record all i can tell you is the way to check where problem is.

1. run this:

   ```
    SELECT  md_businessGroup.businessGroupID  
           from directory d  
        LEFT OUTER JOIN md_department 
                     on d.departmentID =  md_department.departmentID 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN md_businessGroup 
                     on md_department.businessGroupID = md_businessGroup.businessGroupID 
        where directoryID=18230
   ```

if you get the number wrote it down . if you get 0 record here you should check the directory table and test the script again.

2.check ALM_CatalogAudience  again and save the result

```
select * from ALM_CatalogAudience where businessGroupID = the number you just get;
```

if non then ALM_CatalogAudience don't have that groupID. if get records, save it in a temp table.

3. left join ALM_Catalog and the temp table. i think you can get it now

Comment: Hi Raffaello.  Same result as my query above.  No errors but still no rows

Comment: The first select in OP returns 17 rows as seen in Sample Output at the bottom and there are 132 records ALM_CatalogAudience where businessGroupID = 1   Im not sure what other info I can give. It has to be something small im sure, just cat see it

Comment: @Mat41 can't help you with the code cause it don't have logic and syntax error. give some advice about how to check why no record, updated in my answer

Comment: Thank you for your input.   I get 1 returning from your first suggested sql and then using this value I get 133 records for your second query.  This is what I expect and is the reason I dont understand why the complete query returns 0 rows, grrrrrrr    I will try what you ask but I dont understand why the temp table is necessary

Comment: @Mat41 the temp table is just help you to check the result don't have to select again and again. you know we would check the result and try a lot things to find the reason. i want to know if you get any records from step 3.

Comment: Thank you for your help.   I a have updated post with what I believe was the issue

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to fix your original query to match the version that Raffaello.D.Huke fixed up for you.  If your subquery and ALM_CatalogAudience.businessGroupID are both returning 1, it might be that your businessGroupIDs aren't the same type.  Could you try the below?

```
...
AND CAST(ALM_CatalogAudience.businessGroupID AS VARCHAR) = 
  (
      SELECT  CAST(md_businessGroup.businessGroupID AS VARCHAR) 
        from directory d  
...
```

Comment: Hi Robert.  Although not the answer your advice really leads to the problem.  It was problematic because when getting the MAX businessGroupID, if there are ever more than one businessGroups mapped it was never going to return results where businessGroupID=1.  I have updated my post